# Reading method from c# dll

Tags: c#, dll

I have compiled the following code to the assembly file **test.dll**:

```
namespace dll_test
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int DoMagic()
        {
            return 12;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like check my dll using *DLL Export Viewer* but when I did I don't see any function.

[image]

So where is the problem?

Comment: Though a fine concept, be careful with what-ever is loading your managed code because a native process can only load one version of the CLR at a time.  [.NET 4 changes that however with side-by-side execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add your function to the dll-export table. In this table are the names of all functions you are possible to use in an executable. To do this in C# you have to add the Unmanaged Exports (DllExport for .Net) (https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports).

Then add the DllExport in a static method like this:

```
[DllExport("DoMagic", CallingConvention=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static int DoMagic()
{
  return 12;
}
```

you find more information on https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports#TOC-C-: or the msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx

Comment: Whilst your first paragraph is fine, your code sample is not.  What's `DllExport`? I can't find that in c#. That MSDN link is for exporting from **native c++ dlls** not exporting from _c# assemblies_.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to add the NuGet. I will edit it. Thank you.

Comment: Ah I need the NuGet.  Impressive package!  Thanks for the revision. +1  (though I think you should indicate the MSDN link as being _native-centric_)